# #Teradata error expected something like ')' between ';' and the end of the request

Tags: request, syntax-error, teradata-sql-assistant

```
REPLACE MACRO GEO_MATCHED (REGION INTEGER) AS (
INSERT INTO DLA_v.GEO_FULL_2019_MATCHED
              SELECT                
                 Poly.Project_ID AS "Project_ID",
                             Poly.WIKIMAPIA_ID AS "POLY_ID_WIKIMAPIA",
                             Poly.NAME AS "POLY_NAME",
                             
                             Fast.REVENUE_YTD,
                             Fast.JOB_VERTICAL,

                             Poly.geometry.ST_Contains(Fast.geometry)  AS "INSIDE"
              FROM
                            (SELECT * FROM  DLA_A_19143.geo_jobsite_input_data 
                            WHERE region__c = :REGION)Fast, DLA_D_SLSMKT.GEO_POLYGONS Poly
              WHERE
                             (Poly.geometry.ST_Contains(Fast.geometry) = 1;);


 ----region with null values
```

getting this error for this code :
[42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error, expected something like ')' between ';' and the end of the request.

Added the brackets as it has asked to add the bracted between semicolumns and end of request its not working, if any one could help .

Comment: What client tool are you using?  It seems that it may be incorrectly breaking the SQL into two requests at the first `;` delimiter. Does your tool have an option to submit a "multi-statement request" or submit "as a single request"?